# How to update database on load of a page?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am on WORDPRESS and I would like to update the table called **wppl_friends_locator** and more precisely the fields **lat** and **long** of the **logged in user**

Each time the logged in visit the website, it actually grab his coordinates :

```
$latitude = ( !empty( $_COOKIE['gmw_lat'] ) ) ? urldecode( $_COOKIE['gmw_lat'] ) : false;
$longitude = ( !empty( $_COOKIE['gmw_lng'] ) ) ? urldecode( $_COOKIE['gmw_lng'] ) : false;
```

Now I would like that on certain pages, the database gets updated by these values when the user loads these pages...

What to do ? I am very new to PHP I try to understand, I know that I am not on a platform to ask and give the code but it takes me days to figure that kind of things so a little bit of help would be GREATLY appreciated !

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this in your themes functions.php

```
function update_coordinate( $latitude, $longitude ){
    global $current_user;
    global $wpdb;
    $update_result = false;

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $update_arr = array(
            'latitude' => $latitude,
            'longitude' => $longitude
        );

        $update_result = $wpdb->update( 'wppl_friends_locator', $update_arr, array( 'user_id' => $current_user->ID ) );
    }

    return $update_result;
}
```

then call "update_coordinate" function (with latitude and longitude parameters) in your template file. You can call it after "get_footer()".

Here's a sample (i can't post a comment so i'll just add it here). You can also put it in your theme's footer.php after "wp_footer()"

```
$latitude = ( !empty( $_COOKIE['gmw_lat'] ) ) ? urldecode( $_COOKIE['gmw_lat'] ) : false;
$longitude = ( !empty( $_COOKIE['gmw_lng'] ) ) ? urldecode( $_COOKIE['gmw_lng'] ) : false;

update_coordinate( $latitude, $longitude );
```

**UPDATE:** 
Insert if current user has no row on the table

```
function update_coordinate( $latitude, $longitude ){
    global $current_user;
    global $wpdb;
    $query_result = false;

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        # check if user has record
        $row_count = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( 
            "SELECT count(member_id) FROM wppl_friends_locator WHERE member_id = %d", $current_user->ID ) );

        if ( $row_count > 0 ) {
            $update_arr = array(
                'lat' => $latitude,
                'long' => $longitude
            );
            $query_result = $wpdb->update( 'wppl_friends_locator', $update_arr, array( 'member_id' => $current_user->ID ) );

        }else{
            $insert_arr = array(
                'member_id' => $current_user->ID,
                'lat' => $latitude,
                'long' => $longitude
            );
            $query_result = $wpdb->insert( 'wppl_friends_locator', $insert_arr );

        }
    }   

    return $query_result;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you VERY much for this fast answer ! I would love to try but I am not sure what to write as far as the call of the function... A little bit more help ? :p THANKS AGAIN !

Comment: You need to add the parameters, i added a sample in my answer<?php update_coordinate( $latitude, $longitude ); ?>

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I added it where you told me to but it looks like it is not changing anything in the database. I will mark it as solved because I guess it will help people but I am not qualified enough to debug that... Thanks again

Comment: in this code: $wpdb->update( 'wppl_friends_locator', $update_arr, array( 'user_id' => $current_user->ID ) );. Make sure that the 'user_id' field exist in your 'wppl_friends_locator' database table

Comment: can you show me the structure or fields of your database table (wppl_friends_locator)?

Comment: Hello ! OMG ! I didn't see that ! Indeed, my table has "member_id" and "lat" and "long" not user_id, latitude and longitude. Now it is updating but I have ONE problem : when the users register, it doesn't make a row for him in the table "wppl_friends_locator". How can I tweak the code you made so if the logged in user doesn't have a row in the table it creates one with his ID, his lat and long ? THANK YOU SOOOOOO MUCH !

Comment: I edited my previous comment because I only have one little thing I need on it ! Thank you !

Comment: Hello ! THANK YOU ! Do I add only the update code or both of them ?

Comment: remove the old function, replace it with the function that i just added

Comment: It doesn't seem to work anymore... It is not returning any error though ! But it is not updating the database

Comment: However it is adding a row in the database with the appropriate coordinates ! That is good ! The update part seems not to work anymore

Comment: i edit my answer again, i changed this: `$row_count = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT count(member_id) FROM 'wppl_friends_locator' WHERE member_id = %d", array( $current_user->ID ) ) );` to this: `$row_count = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT count(member_id) FROM wppl_friends_locator WHERE member_id = %d", $current_user->ID ) );`

Comment: It is adding a row and the coordinates, no problem for that ! But it is not updating the database if the user already has a row and coordinates in it

Comment: i updated the new function that i added (a very small change)

Comment: You... Are PHENOMENAL. I can not believe it ! I T WORKS ! ONG THANK YOU SO MUCH ! If i ever become successful with that, send me a way to send you millions of dollars ! THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107680/discussion-between-frenchynyc-and-litopj).